# jquery post function with array as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsp, post

i have to pass a array of values to a jsp page.
i am using the following **jquery function**

```
$.post("add.jsp" ,{'URL_Arr': urlarray}, function (data) {   
    alert(urlarray);
    $('#einfo').html(data);
});
```

where,
urlarray is an array.Alert shows me the (urlarray)array values as 48,39,28

And **add.jsp** page conatains the following

```
String URL_Arr1=request.getParameter("URL_Arr");
out.println("arr:"+URL_Arr1);
```

Am getting the `URL_Arr` as `null`

Can any one help me in passing the array values to another jsp page using jquery post.

Comment: Remove quotes around URL_Arr in that code: {'URL_Arr': urlarray}

Comment: @CoolEsh: those quotes are valid.

Answer (score 5):

For arrays, jQuery will suffix the parameter name with `[]`, so use `URL_Arr[]` as parameter name. You should also be using `getParameterValues()` to get all array values. The `getParameter()` would only return the first item.

Summarized:

```
String[] urlarray = request.getParameterValues("URL_Arr[]");
// ...
```